# Remover a ação do botão físico do OptionsMenu

Tags: android

Temos uma aplicação em que estamos removendo a ação  do `OptionsMenu` do botão físico e inserindo na `Toolbar`.

Gostaria de saber se é possível anular a ação do botão físico do Menu?

Gostaria que o Menu fosse exibido apenas na `Toolbar` e não mais no botão físico.

Answer (score 1):

Consegui solucionar meu problema sobreescrevendo o seguinte método: `onMenuOpened` :

```
@Override
public boolean onMenuOpened(int featureId, Menu menu) {
    return false;

}
```

Este método é invocado apenas quando clico no botão físico!